# JavaScript geolocation sporadic in IE

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I have a problem very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591039/geolocation-getcurrentposition-always-fails-in-ie-11), however figured that it was different in a particularly fundamental way enough to warrant its own question. I have a page which requests the user's location once every 2 seconds (very frequent, I know, but it's for a purpose) using `getCurrentPosition()`. Here's my code:

```
function locationWrapper() {
    if (!navigator.geolocation) {
        success = false;
        console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser")
    }
    if (success) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            recordPosition, catchError, { enableHighAccuracy: false }
        );
    }
}
```

The `recordPosition()` function doesn't really do anything pertinent (and is rarely ever reached) to the question. `catchError` looks like this:

```
function catchError(error) {
    console.log(error);
    switch (error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            console.log("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            console.log("Location information is unavailable.");
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            console.log("The request to get user location timed out.");
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            console.log("An unknown error occurred.");
            break;
    }
}
```

All fairly straightforward. This works perfectly in Chrome, and only *sometimes* in IE. That's the baffling thing. It's called once at the very start of the JS document and then once every 2 seconds by a `setInterval()` function. The first one *always* works, and in the interval it works roughly once in 20 times, but otherwise returns the incredibly helpful `POSITION_UNAVAILABLE` error.

**I have tried:**

- Changing the `enableHighAccuracy` option in `getCurrentPosition()` to be `false`, as can be seen in my code
- Ensuring that there are not any issues with the permissions in IE
- Extending the interval period to 5 seconds

Any input is much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

It's specifically IE11. Sorry for missing that out.

**EDIT 2:**

I'm seeing the same behaviour using [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation_error). The first time works (displays coordinates) but afterwards just shows an error until I reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this appears to be a problem with IE that other users are also having. There is a [question](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/11539605/) about it on the Edge and IE support page, but it's been a bit muddied by the OP stating that Edge is also not working (which has performed fine for me) and seems to have been ignored. I have made a comment on the thread and if nothing comes of it I may have to make my own question relating only to IE.

Seems like a pretty big deal to me - if developers can't use `getCurrentLocation()` when they need to, their sites just won't work properly in IE. I hope Microsoft take an interest.